# создать с помощью js новый элемент и поместить в него другой элемент

Tags: javascript

В примере ниже, если нажать на кнопку, создается НОВЫЙ контейнер. 
Далее в этот контейнер нужно переместить элементы из другого блока.
Как только элементы будут перемещены, СТАРЫЙ контейнер нужно удалить.

```css
input {
  margin: 20px 0 40px 40px;
  padding: 10px;
  }

h1 {
  margin: 10px 0 0 40px;
}

.slide-container {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: silver;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.element {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: white;
}

.slide-container_new {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: silver;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<input class="btn" type="button" onclick="AddContainer()" value="добавить новый контейнер" />

<div class="peppermint" id="peppermint">

  <figure id="containerOne">
    <div class="slide-container">
      <div class="element">
        1
      </div>
      <div class="element">
        2
      </div>
      <div class="element">
        3
      </div>
    </div>
  </figure>

  <figure class="slide">
    <div class="slide-container">
      <div class="element">
        меня надо переместить
      </div>
      <div class="element">
        меня надо переместить
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide-container">
      <div class="element">
        6
      </div>
      <div class="element">
        7
      </div>
    </div>
  </figure>

</div>

<script>
  function AddContainer() {
      // эти две строки рабочие!!!
      var newContainer = document.getElementById('containerOne'); // сохраняем в переменной контейнер, куда нужно положить элемент
      newContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', '<div class="slide-container_new id="puthere">контейнер создался, но я не понимаю как переместить сюда элемент</div>');
  }
</script>
```

Я пытаюсь сделать адаптивный слайдер, мне нужно чтобы на большом экране элементы второго слайда перемещались в первый. Пока для тестов вызываю функцию с помощью события onclick.

Comment: если предоставленный код работает - то в чем заключается вопрос?

Comment: Код работает частично. Я с помощью метода insertAdjacentHTML создал новый контейнер, а вот каким образом перетащить в него элементы из другого блока мне не понять. Гугл пока не помог.

Comment: Думаю, разберетесь что с ними нужно делать: [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) и [removeChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так по-идее вам нужно:

```
<input class="btn" type="button" onclick="AddContainer()" value="добавить новый контейнер" />

<div class="peppermint" id="peppermint">

  <figure id="containerOne">
    <div class="slide-container">
      <div class="element">
        1
      </div>
      <div class="element">
        2
      </div>
      <div class="element">
        3
      </div>
    </div>
  </figure>

  <figure class="slide js-slide">
    <div class="slide-container">
      <div class="element js-clone">
        меня надо переместить
      </div>
      <div class="element js-clone">
        меня надо переместить
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide-container">
      <div class="element">
        6
      </div>
      <div class="element">
        7
      </div>
    </div>
  </figure>

</div>

    <script>

    function AddContainer() {
              var newContainer = document.getElementById('containerOne'); // сохраняем в переменной контейнер, куда нужно положить элемент
              newContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', '<div class="slide-container_new" id="puthere"></div>');
              var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.js-clone')
              elements.forEach(function (el) {
                var clone = el.cloneNode(true);
                var puthere = document.getElementById('puthere').appendChild(clone);
               el.parentNode.removeChild(el)
              })
              var containers = document.querySelectorAll('.slide-container')
              containers.forEach(function (el) {
                if (el.children.length == 0) el.parentNode.removeChild(el)
              })        
          }
    </script>
```